# VBS to Search for Multiple Files Recursively in C:\Users

Tags: windows, search, recursion, vbscript

I need to recursively search for multiple files through the C:\Users directory tree recursively.

If I find any of the specified files in any of the sub-directories, I want to echo out the full path.

Here is what I have:

```
Dim fso,folder,files,sFolder,newFolder  
Dim arr1  
arr1 = Array("myFile1.pdf","myFile2.pdf","myFile3.pdf","nutbag.rtf","whoa.txt")  
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
  sFolder = "C:\Users"  
  Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)  
  Set files = folder.SubFolders  
  For each folderIdx In files  
    IF (Instr(folderIdx.Name,"Default") <> 1) Then  
     If (Instr(folderIdx.Name,"All Users") <> 1) Then  
      newFolder = sfolder & "\" & folderIdx.Name  
      CopyUpdater fso.GetFolder(newFolder)  
     End If  
    End If  
  Next  
Sub CopyUpdater(fldr)  
 For Each f In fldr.Files  
  For Each i in arr1  
    If LCase(f.Name) = i Then  
       WScript.echo(f.name)  
    End If  
  Next  
Next  
For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders  
    CopyUpdater sf  
  Next  
End Sub
```

If I run it as 'Administrator', I get:

```
VBScript runtime error: Permission Denied
```

If I run it as 'Local System' user, I get:

```
VBScript runtime error: Path not found
```

If I add, 'On Error Resume Next' to the beginning to suppress the errors, I get nothing back.

I have placed a text file called 'whoa.txt' in numerous locations around the C:\Users sub-dirs.

My suspicion is that it is a Windows permissions thing, but I am unsure.

Thanks much.

Comment: Why don't you post the line numbers where your errors are occurring? User-profile folders in `C:\Users` are secured. Why are you dimming only _some_ of your variables? You're using `LCase()` to convert the filenames to lowercase but many of the files you're searching for aren't in lowercase (`myFile1.pdf`, `myFile2.pdf`, etc.). Why are you assigning a collection of subfolders to a variable named `files`? (Some of these criticisms don't really affect your script, per se, but they make reading it much more difficult).

Answer (score 2):

First I didn't use your code, it confuses me what you are trying to accomplish.

Next you should run the script in <kbd>Administrator</kbd> mode command prompt. This should allow you to check if the file is there.
[image: cmd]

Then paste code below to a **vbs** file and **cscript** it. This code displays all the matched filenames.
My idea is that instead of going through all files in any folder for a matching filename, check if those wanted files exists in that folder - this is generally faster as some folders contains hundreds of files if not thousands (check your Temp folder!).

```
Option Explicit

Const sRootFolder = "C:\Users"
Dim fso
Dim arr1
Dim oDict ' Key: Full filename, Item: Filename

Main

Sub Main
    arr1 = Array("myFile1.pdf", "myFile2.pdf", "myFile3.pdf", "nutbag.rtf", "whoa.txt")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' Call Recursive Sub
    FindWantedFiles(sRootFolder)
    ' Display All Findings from Dictionary object
    DisplayFindings
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oDict = Nothing
End Sub

Sub FindWantedFiles(sFolder)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oFDR, oItem
    ' Check if wanted files are in this folder
    For Each oItem In arr1
        If fso.FileExists(sFolder & "\" & oItem) Then
            oDict.Add sFolder & "\" & oItem, oItem
        End If
    Next
    ' Recurse into it's sub folders
    For Each oFDR In fso.GetFolder(sFolder).SubFolders
        FindWantedFiles oFDR.Path
    Next
End Sub

Sub DisplayFindings()
    Dim oKeys, oKey
    oKeys = oDict.Keys
    For Each oKey In oKeys
        wscript.echo oKey
    Next
End Sub
```